# $G1$ interpolating curves with symmetric slopes in ends of segments

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, interpolation

given a set $\lbrace p_i| 1\le i \le n\rbrace =\lbrace(x_1,y_1),\,\cdots,\,(x_n,y_n)\rbrace$ of points , which method can be recommended to calculate a sequence of angles $\left(\varphi_1,\,\cdots,\,\varphi_n\right)$ with
$$\left(\cos(\varphi_i),\,sin(\varphi_i)\right)^T\left(x_{i+1}-x_i,\,y_{i+1}-y_i\right)=-\left(\cos(\varphi_{i+1}),\,sin(\varphi_{i+1})\right)^T\left(x_{i+1}-x_i,\,y_{i+1}-y_i\right)$$
for cases $i=1,\ i=n-1$ or $\left((p_i-p_{i-1})\times(p_{i+1}-p_i)\right)\cdot\left((p_{i+1}-p_i)\times(p_{i+2}-p_{i+1})\right)\ge 0$
and
$$\left(\cos(\varphi_i),\,sin(\varphi_i)\right)^T\left(x_{i+1}-x_i,\,y_{i+1}-y_i\right)=\left(\cos(\varphi_{i+1}),\,sin(\varphi_{i+1})\right)^T\left(x_{i+1}-x_i,\,y_{i+1}-y_i\right)$$
otherwise,
that minimizes $\max\left|\frac{\left(\cos(\varphi,\,\sin(\varphi)\right)^T\left(x_{i+1}-x_i,\,y_{i+1}-y_i\right)}{\|p_{i+1}-p_i\|}\right|$

Comment: I have the feeling that the problem should have a simple geometric meaning but discerning it from the formulation above is not at all easy. Am I mistaken? If not, can you let us know what it is?

Comment: @fedja your feeling is right; the prototypical case is $G1$ interpolation with circular segments or with quadratic Wilson-Fowler splines. The benefit would be not having issues defining slopes in the first and last point. My hope is that the interpolating curves will tend to have less varying curvature between the nodes.